# Is it possible to show PostgreSQL terminal logs in Airflow Task log using just PostgresOperator?

Tags: airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs, airflow-2.x, postgres-operator

I'm using the PostgresOperator to define tasks in Airflow. Today, i discovered that the PostgresSQL terminal logs such as 'raise notice' or information about number of rows affected didn't show up in the DAG's task log. It is possible to show them without using PythonOperator and launching SQL query from python?

I tried to put SQL query into $$ do block and raise some messages. I expect that this message from database terminal will be included in the task's log.

Comment: What version of Airflow are you using? If you're using Airflow >= 2.0.0, what version of [apache-airflow-providers-postgres](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-postgres/)

Comment: The newest stable version - Airflow 2.5. How can i check version of apache-airflow-providers-postgres?

Comment: That depends on how you're deploying Airflow. So, two questions:

1. How are you deploying Airflow?
2.How did you install `apache-airflow-providers-postgres`?

Comment: I deployed airflow in docker according to this manual: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/docker-compose/index.html

Comment: You can run `docker exec <scheduler container> pip freeze | grep apache-airflow-providers-postgres`

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the version of Airflow, version of `apache-airflow-providers-postgres`, and the DAG code?